# Appium: Ruby: Close and Launch app for each scenario

Tags: android, ruby, automation, cucumber, appium

I have a cucumber test suit to run, and till now, I was having my application reinstalled each time when the scenario ran.

I now in order to have the exection time reduced and also not wanting to have sign ups each time i install the application, I would want to only run the sign up once, and then the rest of the scenarios should log me in directly as I will want to just launch it.

Is there a way in appium i can do so?

After scenario 1
Close the app - Force close(Apart from doing it with adb)
Relanch the app != Reinstall

I have tried to force stop with `shell command am -force stop` 
and also have used

```
Before do 
app_hash = {
 app_package: ""
app_activity: ""
}
appium_device.driver.start_activity app_hash
end
```

Also my desired capabilities set to

```
 Fullreset : false
    noReset: true
```

Please can someone suggest me better way to close(After scenario done) and relaunch(Before scenario begins) each time I run the scenario?

Answer (score 0):

```
Before do
    caps = {your caps}
    @driver = Appium::Driver.new(:caps => caps).start_driver
    # other stuff
end 

After do 
    @driver.quit
end
```

and keep the noReset: true capability in your caps, this will not install eveytime.

Hope it helps!!